# Multiple mysqli_fetch_array without while loop returning nothing

Tags: php

I have multiple tables that I need to retrieve data from. I created several queries to select the data and store in arrays but nothing is being retrieved whereas there no errors. What could be the problem with my code.

I took part of the code and alternatively used a while loop but still got no results.

Below is the sample code.

```
   $output = '';
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$year = $_POST['ddlacyear'];
$term = $_POST['ddlterms'];
if ($year == '1' && $term == 'Term1') {
  $cat1 = 'c111';
  $cat2 = 'c211';
  $cat3 = 'c311';
  $exams = 'e11';
}

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Score FROM `".$cat1."`
  WHERE (AdmNo = '".$user_id."' AND Subject = 101)");
$cat_one_eng = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);


$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Score FROM `".$cat2."`
  WHERE (AdmNo = '".$user_id."' AND Subject = 101)");
$cat_two_eng = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);


$query3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Score FROM `".$cat3."`
  WHERE (AdmNo = '".$user_id."' AND Subject = 101)");
$cat_three_eng = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);


$query4 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Score FROM `".$exams."`
  WHERE (AdmNo = '".$user_id."' AND Subject = 101)");
$main_exams_eng = mysqli_fetch_array($query4);


<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <col width="80">
    <col width="230">
    <col width="45">
    <col width="45">
    <col width="45">
    <col width="60">
    <col width="55">
    <col width="60">
    <col width="50">
    <th>Subject Code</th>
    <th>Subject Name</th>
    <th>Cat 1</th> 
    <th>Cat 2</th>
    <th>Cat 3</th>
    <th>Main Exam</th> 
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Mean Score</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>ENGLISH</td>
    <td>'.$cat_one_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$cat_two_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$cat_three_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$main_exams_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$main_exams_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$main_exams_eng['Score'].'</td>
    <td>'.$main_exams_eng['Score'].'</td>
  </tr>

  </table>
</tbody>
```

There are no syntax errors. The errors here are there is nothing that is displayed on the table.

I just need a table that displays all the results in the individual subjects and the at the bottom I will sum up the totals and average.

Comment: Why not use `UNION` and do one query?

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Its complexity made me to go about this. Furthermore the variables assigned to table name i get them through an if statement.

Comment: I get the feeling that Bad Database Design caused the Complexity that made you consider this as a solution

Comment: This is a very bad design. It is only going to get more difficult to maintain. Abandon it now. We'd be happy to help you with the redesign - just ask a new question with your problem and initial idea about how to solve it.

Comment: I never designed the database it is a mirror of MS Access which the client wants to continue using. I was supposed to link the database to remote MySQL which I did.